# Proving a series converges given that it is bounded below

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If $\sum{p_n}$ is a convergent series such that $p_i \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall i$ and {$q_n$} is a sequence that is bounded below where $q_i \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall i$, I want to show that if $$q_{n+1} \leq q_n+p_n$$ then {$q_n$} converges.

**What I know:**

Given that {$q_n$} is bounded below, if I can show that it is monotonic then by definition it converges.

Also I know that if $\sum{p_n}$ converges then $\lim_{n \to \infty}p_n = 0$

I know I'm missing a key step to show that $q_{n+1} \leq q_n$, if anyone could help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $q_1+\dots+q_n = q_1+(q_2-q_1)+\dots+(q_n-q_{n-1}) \le q_1+p_1+\dots+p_n$ and so $\sum q_n \le q_1+ \sum p_n$ and thus converges since $q_n$ is bounded from below.

Also, $(q_n)_n$ does not have to be monotonic. If $p_n$ is positive, then $q_{n+1}$ can be in between $q_n$ and $q_n+p_n$ or less than $q_n$.

Comment: Ah i see it now, simpler than I thought! Thank you!

Comment: @tannercarbonati You were correct; it is not this simple since this proof is fatally flawed.  Note that $q_{n+1}\le q_1+\sum_{k=1}^np_k$.  But then what?

Comment: @Dr.MV so does it remain that I should prove that {$q_n$} is monotonic?

Comment: You have that $q_n$ is bounded from below and above.  Hence it contains a convergent subsequence.  See if that leads anywhere.

Comment: I guess I should add a little bit more details. Right off the bat, I assumed the $q_n$'s were non-negative, just by shifting all of them up by their lower bound. Since they are non-negative, $\sum q_n$ converges if and only if it is bounded from above, which is what I proved. Hope this helps.

Comment: @matgworker21 No.  How does the sum $\sum q_n$ enter into this discussion?  When summing the telescoping series $\sum_{k=m}^n (q_{k+1}-q_k)$, we obtain $q_{n+1}-q_m\le \sum_{k=m}^np_k$.

Comment: I don't know what "No" refers to. It is clearly true that for non-negative integers $q_n$, $\sum q_n$ converges if and only if $\sum q_n$ is bounded from above. I showed it is bounded above by $q_1+\sum p_n$.

Comment: For the last time, you didn't show that.  When we add $q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_n$ we do not get $q_1+(q_2-q_1)+\cdots (q_n-q_{n-1})$.  This latter telescoping series is the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (q_{k+1}-q_k)$ and the result is $q_n-q_1$ and not the sum of the $q_n$'s..

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now. You should have just said my first equality what wrong

Answer (score 1):

> The following proof is a generalization of that given by @zhw. in [This Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231206/proving-a-sequence-converges-cauchy).

---

**Given Information:**

The sequence $q_n$ satisfies the conditions that $(i)$

$$q_{n+1}-q_n\le p_n\tag 1$$

for some sequence $p_n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k$ converges, and $(ii)$ $q_n$ is bounded below.

---

**Implication of Convergence of $\,\,\,\,\,\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n$**

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n$ converges, then from the Cauchy criterion, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $N$ such that whenever $N''>N'>N$, $$\sum_{n=N'}^{N''}p_n<\epsilon/2\tag 2$$

---

**Consequence of Lower Bound on $q_N$**

Since $q_n$ is bounded below, then its limit inferior exists and is finite.  We denote the limit inferior as $q$ and write $\displaystyle q=\liminf_{n\to \infty}q_n$.

Then, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $N$ such that

$$q_n>q-\epsilon\tag 3$$

for all $n>N$.

Furthermore, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a subsequence $n_k$ such that

$$ \displaystyle q_{n_k}<q+\epsilon/2 \tag4$$

---

**Putting It Together:**

Now, given $\epsilon>0$, we see from $(2)$ that there exists a $k_0$ large enough so that $\sum_{n_{k_0}}^{n_{k_0}+m}p_n <\epsilon/2$.

And we have from $(1)$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=n_{k_0}}^{n_{k_0}+m}(q_{n+1}-q_n)&=q_{n_{k_0}+m}-q_{n_{k_0}}\\\\
&\le \sum_{n=n_{k_0}}^{n_{k_0}+m}p_n\\\\
&<\epsilon/2
\end{align}$$

whereupon rearranging yields

$$q_{n_{k_0}+m}-q\le (q_{n_{k_0}}-q)+\epsilon/2 \tag 5$$

Applying $(4)$ to $(5)$ shows that

$$q_{n_{k_0}+m}-q\le \epsilon \tag 6$$

Finally, combining $(3)$ and $(6)$, we find that given $\epsilon>0$,

$$-\epsilon< q_n-q < \epsilon$$

whenever $n>N=n_{k_0}$.

> And this completes the proof that $q_n$ converges!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution from one of my friends.

Define $c_n=q_n-q_{n+1}$, proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|<\infty$ will gives us that $\{q_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and thus is convergent. For this reason, it is sufficent to prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|<\infty$.

It should be notice that $-c_n\le p_n$ since $q_{n+1}\le q_n+p_n$. Define $N_1=\{n\in\mathbb{N}|c_n\ge 0\}$ and $N_2=\{n\in\mathbb{N}|c_n< 0\}$. Then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n|c_k|&=\sum_{k\in N_1,k\le n}c_k-\sum_{k\in N_2,k\le n}c_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nc_k-2\sum_{k\in N_2,k\le n}c_k\\
&\le q_1-q_{n+1}+2\sum_{k\in N_2,k\le n}p_k\\
&\le q_1-q+2P,
\end{align*}

where $q$ is a lower bound of $\{q_n\}$ and $P=\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k<\infty$. Since this holds for all $n$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|<\infty$, the proof is complete.